# Does $V=W\oplus W^\perp$ if $W$ is not closed?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(V,\left<\cdot ,\cdot \right>)$ a Hilbert space. Let $W\leq V$ a closed subspace. Then, I proved that $$V=W\oplus W^\perp.$$

My question : Does it still hold if $W$ is not closed ? I think it's not, but I can't provide a counter example. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick your favourite non-closed, dense space $W$. Then we have $W^\perp=\{0\}$ and hence the equality doesn't hold.

Answer (score 2):

Take $V=\ell^{2}$ and let $W$ be the space of finitely non - zero sequences. Then $W^{\perp}=\{0\}$ so $W+W^{\perp} \neq V$.